# python "send" method doesn't change the value of "next"?

Tags: python, generator, return-value, send, yield

I'm trying generator's send function, I was expecting that send will change the value that's being yield, so I tried in ipython:

```
In [17]: def z(n):
    ...:     i=0
    ...:     while(i<n):
    ...:         val=yield i
    ...:         print "value is:",val
    ...:         i+=1
    ...:
In [24]: z1=z(10)
In [25]: z1.next()
Out[25]: 0

In [26]: z1.send(5) # I was expecting that after "send", output value will become "5"
value is: 5
Out[26]: 1

In [27]: z1.next()
value is: None # I was expecting that z1.next() will restart from "6" because I sent "5"
Out[27]: 2
```

Well I suppose I had wrong understanding of what "send" really does, how to correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're yielding `i` but you're not assigning the return value from `yield` statement to it. If you assign the return value you will see the output you expect:

```
def z(n):
    print 'Generator started'
    i=0
    while(i<n):
        val=yield i
        print "value is:",val
        if val is not None:
            i = val
        i+=1

z1=z(10)
print 'Before start'
print z1.next()
print z1.send(5)
print z1.next()
```

Output:

```
Before start
Generator started
0
value is: 5
6
value is: None
7
```

**Update:** When `send` or `next` is called for the first time the generator is executed from start to the first `yield` statement at which point value is returned to the caller. This is why `value is:` text is not seen on first call. When `send` or `next` is called for second time the execution resumes from `yield`. If `send` was called the parameter given to it is returned by the `yield` statement, otherwise `yield` returns `None`.

Comment: If I just use z1.next(), it prints numbers; when using "print z1.next()" the "value is" statement appears. Why?

Comment: @Troskyvs Updated answer a bit, hopefully that answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I began to understand your point, inside the generator the "val=yield i" means val is set from outer "send" command, while the outer caller gets return value from "yield i". This is really tricky to understand why "next()" equals to "send(None)" and thus val is "None".